# Join 3 tables to update and insert

Tags: sql, oracle, join, merge

I am trying to insert and update data to B69_TBL_ALERTA_CONCENTRADO concentrado from 3 tables, both B69_CAT_ALERTA_FILE, TBL_INTERLOCUTORES and B69_TBL_ALERTA alert.
With 2 INNER JOIN it works, but adding the third table to it fails.
It says invalid identifier ID_ALERTA.
The insertion and updating is not a problem, that's why I don't add that code.

```
MERGE INTO B69_TBL_ALERTA_CONCENTRADO concentrado USING (
    SELECT
        inter.rfc as inter_rfc,
        alerta.id_alerta,
        archivo.id_archivo,
        archivo.rfc,
        archivo.nombre_contribuyente,
        archivo.situacion_contribuyente,
        archivo.oficio_global,
        archivo.publicacion_presuntos,
        archivo.publicacion_definitivos
    FROM
        B69_CAT_ALERTA_ARCHIVO archivo
        INNER JOIN TBL_INTERLOCUTORES inter ON inter.rfc = archivo.rfc
        INNER JOIN B69_TBL_ALERTA alerta ON concentrado.id_alerta = alerta.id_alerta
) v_using ON (concentrado.rfc = v_using.rfc)
```

ERROR

> Error (): PL / SQL: ORA-00904: "CONCENTRADO". "ID_ALERTA": invalid identifier

Comment: Are you sure concentrado.id_alerta exists? That seems to be what the error message is suggesting.

Comment: yes, that field does exist in both tables that I am trying to relate, in fact what I am trying to do by rfc that also exists in both tables and it does not allow either.

Comment: Ah I see the issue, you can't reference concentrado inside your subselect query, try joining alerta on a id thats present inside the subquery.

Comment: It seems that the offending condition should not be in the `on` clause of the last join within the `using` clause of `merge`. Instead, it should be moved to the `on` clause of the `merge` statement itself, last line of the code you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
MERGE INTO B69_TBL_ALERTA_CONCENTRADO concentrado USING (
    SELECT
        inter.rfc as inter_rfc,
        alerta.id_alerta,
        archivo.id_archivo,
        archivo.rfc,
        archivo.nombre_contribuyente,
        archivo.situacion_contribuyente,
        archivo.oficio_global,
        archivo.publicacion_presuntos,
        archivo.publicacion_definitivos
    FROM
        B69_CAT_ALERTA_ARCHIVO archivo
        INNER JOIN TBL_INTERLOCUTORES inter ON inter.rfc = archivo.rfc
        INNER JOIN B69_TBL_ALERTA alerta ON  alerta.id_alerta = inter.rfc 
) v_using ON (concentrado.rfc = v_using.rfc and concentrado.id_alerta = v_using.id_alerta)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
   SELECT 1 FROM B69_TBL_ALERTA_CONCENTRADO concentrado JOIN (
        SELECT
            inter.rfc as inter_rfc,
            alerta.id_alerta,
            archivo.id_archivo,
            archivo.rfc,
            archivo.nombre_contribuyente,
            archivo.situacion_contribuyente,
            archivo.oficio_global,
            archivo.publicacion_presuntos,
            archivo.publicacion_definitivos
        FROM
            B69_CAT_ALERTA_ARCHIVO archivo
            INNER JOIN TBL_INTERLOCUTORES inter ON inter.rfc = archivo.rfc
            INNER JOIN B69_TBL_ALERTA alerta ON concentrado.id_alerta = alerta.id_alerta
    ) v_using ON (concentrado.rfc = v_using.rfc);
```

If it is wrong, you have problem matching the tables, if not, you have the problem with MERGE.